# How to do a loop with different start and end data date in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a panel data with a quarterly time series for each ID that has different start and end date. I'd like to run a rolling regression on each ID with 10 obs. I'm wondering how I can write a loop to do it. For instance for each ID, I'd like to run a regression from the first obs from date 19880831- 19910228 and then from the second obs 19890228-19910531 and so on and so forth until the last date for this ID. Each ID, however, has a different start and end date. Thanks.

Comment: You say 10 obs? So how many points for each regression?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following macro with nested `do` loops. Outer loop iterates through panel IDs and inner loop skips every 10 to filter data by the row number `_N_` value. Regression results are then saved into individual one-line `results` data sets suffixed by id and current multiple of 10. Be sure to change the loops limits, (*50*, *1000*) to accommodate data.

```
%macro rollingregression;
    %do i = 1 %to 50;                 ** ID LOOP;
        %do j = 1 %to 1000;           ** OBS LOOP; 
            data new_data;
                set current_data;       
                if ID = &i;     
                if _N_ >= &j & _N_ <= (&j + 9);
            run;

            proc reg data = new_data noprint outest=results&i&j;
                model y = x1 x2 x3;
            quit;
        %end;
    %end;
%mend rollingregression;

%rollingregression;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. However, it seems that your code runs the data from 1-10 then 21-30 and etc. What I'd like to have is to run from 1-10 and then 2-11 and etc. Here's a sample of the data:

Comment: Ok. I do not see sample data but I updated the inner obs loop by removing the `%by 10` and adjusting the `_N_` if range.

Comment: Curious, did macro loop update work? Or did you go entirely different route?